# what kind of javascript encryption is this?

Tags: javascript, redirect, encryption

what kind of encryption is this?

```
<script>function redir(){var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.open('GET','xxx.com');xhr.timeout=5000;xhr.ontimeout=xhr.onload=function(){var _='',m=Math,c=m.ceil(m.pow(m.E*m.PI,m.E)/m.E),s='**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**';for(var i=c-c;i<s.split(String.fromCharCode(103)).length;++i){var t=parseInt(c)-s.split(String.fromCharCode(103))[i].length;_+=String.fromCharCode(t);}window.location=_.substring(0,_.length -1);};xhr.send();}</script>
```

this is a redirect code, and the encrypt returns final part of a URL.

> /abranco-128-gb-6-1-8-gb-ram-cam-tripla-16-mp-selfie-10-mp.htm

Comment: IIUC, simply based on the char set, looks like base64.

Comment: @S3DEV Looks much weirder than that. It's using `g` as a delimiter in `split()`, and then using the lengths of the substrings as part of a character code. `t=parseInt(c)-s.split(String.fromCharCode(103))[i].length; _+=String.fromCharCode(t);`

Comment: this is not sounding simple , I will try make the reverse process